# Route.config de website em c# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Estou a construir um site. Mas há uma questão que não consigo resolver. 
Tenho um Home Controller, onde tenho todas as Views do site. 
Por exemplo, eu entro [image: nesta view] e quando clico numa das imagens para ir para outra View, [image: por exemplo], o meu URL não aparece como eu queria. Eu queria que aparecesse -> [image: Exemplo]

Excerto do código da View Relva de Futebol:

```
<div class="gallery">
        <a href="/Home/DOMOSlide">
            <img src="~/Imagens/Slide DS.jpg" alt="DOMO Slide DS">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">DOMO® Slide DS</div>
    </div>
```

Terá de ser no Route.config?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SiteTESTE
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Miguel, coloque as imagens da própria pergunta, fica mais fácil de visualizar. Segundo, coloque seu código, em especial a definição das rotas no `global.asax.cs` e um exemplo das `actions` da home, como `RelvaFutebol`

Comment: Já atualizei a minha pergunta. o global.asax.cs não alterei desde o início do projeto.

Comment: No seu projeto deve ter uma pasta `App_Start` e dentro um arquivo `RouteConfig.cs`, se possível, adicione ele na pergunta,

Comment: Já adicionei o código do Route.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixe o seu `RouteConfig.cs` assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SiteTESTE
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "RelvaFutebol",
                url: "Home/RelvaFutebol/DOMOSlide",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DOMOSlide", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );          

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Note que foi adicionado uma nova rota, ela tem o nome **RelvaFutebol** e a `URL` para acessar ela é `Home/RelvaFutebol/DOMOSlide` e irá acessar o `Controler Home` e a `Action DOMOSlide`

A rota **`Dafault`** deve ir ao final, pois sempre irá acessar a rota que se encaixar primeiro e, na maioria dos casos, a **`Default`** é a que se encaixa

Conforme comentado, você pode definir para que a `action` seja dinâmica

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RelvaFutebolDinamica",
    url: "Home/RelvaFutebol/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DOMOSlide", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Outra dica é altear o seu `HTML` para:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="@Url.Action("DOMOSlide","Home")">
        <img src="~/Imagens/Slide DS.jpg" alt="DOMO Slide DS">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">DOMO® Slide DS</div>
</div>
```

Com o `@Url.Action("DOMOSlide","Home")` automaticamente ele irá criar um link para a rota desse `controller`, gerando um `html` com `href="Home/RelvaFutebol/DOMOSlide"`

Você pode ver mais na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) e também nessa [página](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc) que explica sobre o assunto(está em inglês)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! Só mais uma questão, eu tenho diferentes tipos de relva para cada desporto, por exemplo: na RelvaFutebol tenho a DOMOSlide, DOMOVarioslide e DOMODuraforce ou seja, preciso de fazer para cada tipo de relva certo?

Comment: Nesse caso no ultimo parâmetro você pode adicionar `{action}`, assim pegará a `action` passada, editei a pergunta e adicionei o exemplo

Comment: Ok obrigado! :)